# How do I convert this SQL Server query to PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

Please I need help. How do I convert this SQL Server query to PostgreSQL? Thank you.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    DATENAME('m', started_at) + ' ' + CAST(DATEPART(yyyy, started_at) AS varchar) AS year_month,
    bike_type,
    user_type,
    COUNT(*) AS no_of_rides
FROM
    Final_Data
GROUP BY
    DATENAME('m', started_at) + ' ' + CAST(DATEPART(yyyy, started_at) AS varchar),
    bike_type, user_type
```

Comment: Please always explain what the old query is doing. You can't expect that all people that know Postgres also know all features of SQLServer

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    to_char(started_at,'YYYY-MM') year_month, 
    bike_type,
    user_type,
    count(*) AS no_of_rides
FROM
    Final_Data
GROUP BY
    1,2,3;
```

Comment: These answers are really helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `to_char(started_at, 'YYYY-MM')` to extract the year and month.

```
select distinct 
  to_char(started_at, 'YYYY-MM')
    as year_month, 
  bike_type,user_type,count(*)
     as no_of_rides
from Final_Data
group by 
  to_char(started_at, 'YYYY-MM'),
  bike_type,  
  user_type;
```